# Servlet filters as security for web aplication

Tags: java, security, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to do my own custom registration system like we have on most of web sites:

1. User put password username e-male and so on
2. After registration process tries to log in with inserted user name and passwords from registration form.

I was considering to do this with spring-security, but I want to do this with servlets because it's essential things to know for each web developer.

As my particular view I was thinking to use filters.
Would you suggest something for me to read about filters and also how to perform security with servlets and filters??

Thank you with best regards.

Comment: Hover your mouse over the servlet-filters tag in the question. A pop up will show, then select the info option. It will led you to StackOverflow Servlet-Filters wiki that provides a basic example of this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I'm just asking for example how people do this. Nothing done so far. That why I'm asking is it possible to do this with pure servlets and how where to start

Comment: Spring-security does it, so there's no reason you can't. Google for tutorials, read the javadoc, and experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned if its a homeowork assignment. If you are working on a real web application which is going to be used by people, don't reinvent the wheel. I would strongly recommend [spring-security](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/) or other out of box frameworks.

If you are looking for playing around the things for the sake understanding, you can go ahead with whatever you are looking for (filters/servlets).

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at realms and valves (at least in Tomcat). But Servlets are definitely the easiest way.